# Theme Customizer - My panel disappears

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a problem, I create my panel in a normal way, but when I see it after 1 second it disappears, I do not understand what is happening, does anyone know why?
Link Video: http://recordit.co/poHGr09I3d
My code:

```
add_action( 'customize_register',  'add_custom2' );
function add_custom2( $wp_customize ){

        /**
         * Add Header Settings Panel 
         */
        $wp_customize->add_panel(
            'pf-panel-test-1', 
            array(
                'priority'       => 10,
                'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
                'theme_supports' => '',
                'title'          => esc_html__( 'Header PX', 'faceblog' ),
                ) 
        );

        /**
         * Header Menu Section
         */
        $wp_customize->add_section(
            'pf-section-01',
            array(
                'title'         => esc_html__( 'Menu PX', 'faceblog' ),
                'priority'      => 20,
                'panel'         => 'pf-panel-test-1'
            )
        );

        // Menu Featured Image
        $wp_customize->add_setting( 
            'pf-algo-set-01',
            array(
                'default'           => '',
                'capability'        => 'edit_theme_options',
                'sanitize_callback' => 'esc_url_raw',
                ) 
        );

        $wp_customize->add_control(
            'pf-algo-set-01', 
            array(
                  'type' => 'text',
                  'label' => esc_html__( 'About Us link text', 'faceblog' ),
                  'section' => 'pf-section-01',
                  //'settings'=> 'pf-algo-set-01',
                  'priority' => 20,
                )
        );

}
```

**UPDATE & RESOLVE**

1) I am using this function

```
if( is_admin() || is_customize_preview() )
    add_action( 'customize_register', array( &$this, 'add_customizer_fields') );
else
    return false;
```

I thought it would help me to optimize that it only show when it is in the administrator area, but it is not so, in the web page this returns `false`

I add this:

```
if(!function_exists('wp_get_current_user')) {
    include(ABSPATH . "wp-includes/pluggable.php"); 
}
$is_user_admin =  current_user_can('administrator');
if( is_admin() || is_customize_preview() || $is_user_admin )
    add_action( 'customize_register', array( &$this, 'add_customizer_fields') );
else
    return false;
```

With this it makes it enter when it is an administrator user and already it works.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `theme_supports` and `capability` keys?

Comment: your setting and control id are same. change and try

Comment: There is something strange, if I put this code inside the `functions.php` folder of the theme folder, this works, but if I put this code inside a _plugin_ (which executes first than the `functions.php`) this is hidden, they know because this happens ?

Comment: Long story short: this happens if you only register the customizer controls when `is_admin()` is true. Thanks for figuring this out!